# checking requirement for apt-get update .

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am writing a script (Ubuntu) to perform:

> sudo apt-get update

followed by installation of some libs. My question is :

**is there a way to check the requirement of performing *`apt-get update`*? Because running update takes some time. **

It seems not possible. However, I thought perhaps someone know a trick.

Comment: display a message "checking for updates". Then a follow up msg "On to the next thing". Then users have an idea why it seems to be taking so long. People don't mind waiting (as much), if they know something is happening. Good luck.

Comment: What does "check the requirement of performing apt-get update" mean?